# How the ubuntu handle the jiffies wrap around problem?

Tags: ubuntu

After my embedded linux system boot up, the 64bits jiffies returned by

```
# include <sys/times.h>

long long unsigned int tmpJiffies = times(NULL);

printf("the tmpJiffies is 0x%llx.\n", tmpJiffies);
```

will be 0xffff ffff ffff b22b.

And after 5 minutes the return value will wrap around to zero and keep increasing.

I found in the source of linux kernel \include\linux\jiffies.h
there is code like this:

```
/*
 * Have the 32 bit jiffies value wrap 5 minutes after boot
 * so jiffies wrap bugs show up earlier.
 */
#define INITIAL_JIFFIES ((unsigned long)(unsigned int) (-300*HZ))
```

That is why the jiffies wrap around after 5 minutes since system bootup.

But when I try it on my ubuntu linux machine, the jiffies returned value is different.
It is start from 0x6667bf66.

I want to know how can ubuntu do this?